# What makes a Kohen not a Kohen?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, intermarriage

1. If a Kohen has sex with a non-Jew do they lose their Kohen status forever?
2. If a Kohen becomes impure through lesser means, for example walking on a grave or touching a dead body, do they lose their priestly rights forever?
3. What if anything, can cause a kohen to lose their status indefinitely.

Answer (score 4):

You asked:

> **If a Kohen has sex with a non-Jew do they lose their Kohen status forever?**

No - once a Kohen always a Kohen. However, a child born from such a union would be a damaged Kohen; a Chalal who has a lesser status than a Kohen.

But he would be whipped 39 lashes, as per Rambam [הלכות איסורי ביאה - פרק שבעה עשר](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02009.html#HtmpReportNum0016_L2):

> **ו:** כָּל **כֹּהֵן הַבָּא עַל הַכּוּתִית** בֵּין גָּדוֹל בֵּין הֶדְיוֹט **לוֹקֶה מִשּׁוּם זוֹנָה**. שֶׁהֲרֵי אֵינָהּ בַּת קִדּוּשִׁין וְהוּא אָסוּר בִּבְעִילַת זוֹנָה בֵּין יִשְׂרְאֵלִית בֵּין כּוּתִית: ‏

You asked:

> **If a Kohen becomes impure through lesser means, for example walking on a grave or touching a dead body, do they lose their priestly rights forever?**

They do not lose their status at all, however they may not eat Terumah nor enter the Temple while impure.

If a Kohen  purposely become impure or marries somebody he is forbidden from marrying, he is prevented from doing the Temple service until he publically repents, as per Rambam [הלכות ביאת המקדש - פרק ששי](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02001.html#HtmpReportNum0023_L2)
 .

> **ט:** כֹּהֵן שֶׁהָיָה **נוֹשֵׂא נָשִׁים בַּעֲבֵרָה אֵינוֹ עוֹבֵד עַד שֶׁיַּדִּירוּהוּ בֵּית דִּין עַל דַּעַת רַבִּים** כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹּא יִהְיֶה לוֹ הֲפָרָה שֶׁלֹּא יוֹסִיף לַחֲטֹא וְעוֹבֵד וְיוֹרֵד וּמְגָרֵשׁ. וְכֵן אִם הָיָה **מִטַּמֵּא לְמֵתִים פָּסוּל עַד שֶׁיְּקַבֵּל עָלָיו בְּבֵית דִּין שֶׁלֹּא יִטַּמֵּא**. וְאִם עָבַר וְעָבַד קֹדֶם שֶׁיַּדִּיר אוֹ שֶׁיְּקַבֵּל אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא נָשׂוּי בַּעֲבֵרָה לֹא חִלֵּל עֲבוֹדָה: ‏

You asked:

> **What if anything, can cause a kohen to lose their status indefinitely.**

Nothing. Once a Kohen always a Kohen. However, if they do temple-service outside the Temple, then they are invalidated from ever doing Temple service again. If they kill somebody or try convert to another religion they may not bless the people with the priestly blessings as per Rambam [הלכות תפילה וברכת כהנים - פרק חמשה עשר](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01999.html#HtmpReportNum0018_L2).

> **ג:** הָעֲבֵרָה כֵּיצַד. **כֹּהֵן  שֶׁהָרַג אֶת הַנֶּפֶשׁ** אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁעָשָׂה תְּשׁוּבָה לֹא יִשָּׂא אֶת כַּפָּיו שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ישעיה א-טו) 'יְדֵיכֶם דָּמִים מָלֵאוּ' וּכְתִיב (ישעיה א-טו) 'וּבְפָרִשְׂכֶם כַּפֵּיכֶם' וְגוֹ'. **וְכֹהֵן שֶׁעָבַד כּוֹכָבִים** בֵּין בְּאֹנֶס בֵּין בִּשְׁגָגָה אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁעָשָׂה תְּשׁוּבָה אֵינוֹ נוֹשֵׂא אֶת כַּפָּיו לְעוֹלָם שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (מלכים ב כג-ט) 'אַךְ לֹא יַעֲלוּ כֹּהֲנֵי הַבָּמוֹת' וְגוֹ'. וּבְרָכָה כַּעֲבוֹדָה הִיא שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר  (דברים י-ח) 'לְשָׁרְתוֹ וּלְבָרֵךְ בִּשְׁמוֹ'. וְכֵן **כֹּהֵן שֶׁהֵמִיר לְעַכּוּ''ם**  אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁחָזַר בּוֹ אֵינוֹ נוֹשֵׂא אֶת כַּפָּיו לְעוֹלָם. וּשְׁאָר הָעֲבֵרוֹת אֵין מוֹנְעִין: ‏

Comment: I thought a _kohen_ who purposely weds a someone forbidden to him does not bless the people. Is that mistaken?

Comment: @msh210 - you are correct - it says so in the Kitzur, but I can't find it in the Rambam.

Comment: I recommend that you add that a kohen can be invalidated for temple service (and therefore nesiyas capayim) due to mumin.